# How to avoid disabled background on alert messages in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Please let me know how can i avoid a disabled background while displaying an alert message in flex. I want to be able input ie click or key stroke while the alert box is being displayed? Is it possible? how?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the PopUpManager to display a popup instead of using the Alert class.  Set the modal property in the createPopUp() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling Alert.show, add the NONMODAL flag to the flags parameter. So something like this:

```
Alert.show('Alert Text', 'Alert Title', Alert.YES|Alert.NO|Alert.NONMODAL);
```

Strange, but it should work.

[Source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Alert.html#show%28%29)

Comment: Great. It's good etiquette to mark this answer as the correct one, by clicking the checkbox under its score - people in the future are more likely to answer your questions if you do this.